# Screen won't boot on second startup

Tags: boot, simulink

I'm working with the image from Simulink Support Package for Raspberry Pi: https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/raspberry-pi-simulink.html

and using a 5V 2.5A power supply.

When I first install above package, the Raspberry Pi boots and the screen follows. If I restart my system, same scenario. However, if I do a full shutdown using `sudo shutdown -h now`, next time I start up I won't get any monitor action. Despite this everything from the Raspberry Pi can still be accessed and controlled using PuTTy from my laptop using an ethernet cable.

Is there a specific reason for this, a setting I've forgotten, or is it simply the package that are corrupt in some way?

Should be noted that I've reinstalled the package several times, with same result.

Comment: This is similar enough to your problem to at least warrant a look: [comp.sys.raspberry-pi](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.sys.raspberry-pi/AvomxENTVzA/discussion)

Answer (score 0):

I found the oddest workaround, but it works as a temporary fix.

After install, the system can be turned on, monitor boots. Shutdown RPi, then turn it back on, no monitor boot. However, if on second boot I use PuTTy from my laptop to use a reboot command, which forces a reboot of the RPi, it will once again boot, now with monitor working fine.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.